# Bar lines in wrong place after removing staff lines

Tags: notation, rhythm, lilypond

I need to set a rhythm-only piece in lilypond without staff lines. The following almost works but it puts the bar lines in the wrong place. It thinks I'm in 4/4 when I set it to 3/4.

```
\score {
\new Staff   \with {
  \time 3/4
  \override StaffSymbol #'transparent = ##t
  \override Clef #'transparent = ##t
  }
\relative c'' { b4 b4. b8 | b4. b8 b4 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just move the time signature declaration into the right spot, and it works:

```
\score {
\new Staff   \with {
  \override StaffSymbol #'transparent = ##t
  \override Clef #'transparent = ##t
  }
\relative c'' { \time 3/4 b4 b4. b8 | b4. b8 b4 }
}
```

---

When I am making a rhythm, I usually do it a slightly different way:

By using `DrumStaff`, you get a percussion clef (which may or may not be what you want).

By using `drummode` and `bd` (bass drum), the midi file (if you are generating one) will sound like a bass drum which can be useful.

```
\version "2.19.83"

\score{

    \new DrumStaff \with {
        \override StaffSymbol.line-count = #0
        \override BarLine.bar-extent = #'(-2 . 2) } {
            \time 3/4
            \drummode {
                bd4 4. 8 | 
                4. 8 4 |
            }
    }

    \layout {}

    \midi {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought I had tried that, but apparently not in this combination.  I tried a variety of different ways to get rid of the staff, but this was the only one that let me keep the bar lines.